# Относительный импорт в Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-import

Имеется проект:

```
project
    |__library
    |      |__python
    |             |__resource
    |                    |__ __init__.py
    |__web
         |__gui
              |__main.py
```

запуск проекта осуществляется через запуск файла web/gui/main.py, но при выполнении этого запуска появляется ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web/gui/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import library.python.resource as resource
ImportError: No module named python.resource
```

Я запускаю из папки `project`:

```
python web/gui/main.py
```

Как правильно запустить проект что-бы он увидел этот модуль?

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы запускаете скрипт напрямую, то он автоматически считает директорию, в которой находится этот скрипт, корневой. Таким образом, всё что находится выше неё, будет недоступно, если только вы не добавите нужный путь для импорта в `sys.path` (что не очень хорошо).

Поэтому у вас есть 2 выхода:

1. Создать начальный скрипт в корневой директории проекта, изначально запускать его, а уже потом импортировать другие модули
2. Запускать `main.py` как модуль, с помощью параметра -`m` (и это наиболее правильный подход). Таким образом, корневая директория сохранится, и вы сможете спокойно импортировать любой модуль в проекте. Делается это следующим образом:

`python -m web.gui.main`

Помимо этого, для python 2.x необходимо каждую папку, которая так или иначе участвует в импорте, объявить пакетом (т.е. добавить в неё `__init__.py`). В вашем случае, это нужно сделать с папками: `library`, `python`, `web` и `gui`. При этом, для Python 3.x такая необходимость уже отпадает. Спасибо @jfs за дополнение.

Советую почитать:

- [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)
- [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) (см. пункт про параметр -m)
- [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) (python 3.x)

Comment: без добавления `__init__.py` это не будет работать.

Comment: @jfs чуть позже попробую ещё раз, но у меня вроде бы работало (если `__init__.py` есть хотя бы в финальных папках, т.е. в `gui` и `resource` в данном случае). По крайней мере в 3-ке. Отпишусь как проверю.

Comment: мы обсуждаем Python 2. В каждую папку, которую вы Питон-пакетом считаете, следует `__init__.py` добавить, а не только в самую вложенную.

Comment: @jfs Да, сорри, не обратил внимание на версию. Ответ обновил.

Comment: В Питоне 3, если не добавить `__init__.py`, то создаются namespace пакеты -- это будет работать, но семантически не правильно здесь namespace пакеты использовать (они для другого: когда у вас пакет по нескольким папкам может быть разбросан). Как на Питоне 2 так и 3, если вы хотите папку считать Питон-пакетом, добавляйте `__init__.py`.

Comment: @jfs да, всё верно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В каждую папку, которую вы хотите в Питон пакет превратить, добавьте `__init__.py` файлы.

Можно ещё `main.py` в `__main__.py` переименовать, тогда можно запустить скрипт как:

```
project/$ python -m web.gui
```

Так как `project/` в pythonpath в этом случае, то `import library.python.resource` это абсолютный импорт (`library` — это верхнего уровня пакет). В модулях, запущенных как скрипты (`__name__ == '__main__'`), есть ограничения на относительный импорт. `-m` форма допускает явные относительные импорты ([PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)).